# OpenStack4J: How do I list roles for identity(keystone) v3?

Tags: openstack, keystone, openstack4j

I am using [OpenStack4J](http://www.openstack4j.com/) as a client to [OpenStack](https://www.openstack.org/) Identity (keystone) v2. I am able to successfully authenticate and to list roles using OpenStack4J against keystone v2.

I've now started to port my software to use identity(keystone) v3. OpenStack4J supports keystone v3 for token authentication. I've implemented this and successfully obtained domain-scoped tokens. However, I can't figure out how to list roles for keystone v3 via OpenStack4J. For keystone v3, the OS-KSADM API was consolidated into a core API but OpenStack4J still is using the old OS-KSADM extension API. Maybe OpenStack4J doesn't fully support keystone v3? Or maybe I'm missing something.

Can someone help me understand how to use OpenStack4J to list roles against a keystone v3 endpoint?